# How to create a simple publisher to publish current time?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello guys!
I am a ros and cpp beginner and I have read the simple ros publisher tutorial given in the wiki. I want to create a simple publisher that can publish time every second. how can I modify the code given in the tutorial to do the same.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/168421/how-to-create-a-simple-publisher-to-publish-current-time-?/) by [keshav_sarraf](https://answers.ros.org/users/18286/keshav_sarraf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2014-05-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you can use [Timers](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Timers) in ros to count  seconds in one variable , and in your callback event for Timer you can publish Time over ros .

for this you can use [std_msg::int64](http://docs.ros.org/api/std_msgs/html/msg/Int64.html)

---

Originally posted by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) with karma: 1769 on 2014-05-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0